# how to return variable in excel import

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I need to return to controlling the id of the products entered by the excel import.

**ProductImport.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class ProductImport implements  ToCollection {
    public function collection(Collection $rows) {
       foreach ($rows as $row) {
           $product = Product::create([
               'name' => $row[0],
               'detail' => $row[1]                
           ])->id;
       }
       return $product;
    }
}
```

**ProductController.php**

```
public function uploadProducts(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'import_file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('import_file');
    $import = new ProductImport;
    Excel::import($import, $path);
    //Here, how can I return the id of the products that were entered?
    return response()->json(['message' => 'uploaded successfully'], 200);
}
```

I have not found a way to return variables in excel import. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by **public** variable of `ProductImport` class and then use it in your Controller.

First, create one public variable `$product_ids` in Import class, assign it all ids

```
class ProductImport implements  ToCollection
{
    public $product_ids; // declare one public variable

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
       foreach ($rows as $row) {

         // store created product ids as array
           $this->product_ids[] = Product::create([
               'name' => $row[0],
               'detail' => $row[1]
           ])->id;
       }

       return $product;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the Import class variable in your Controller as below.

```
$import->product_ids;
```

Full code:

```
public function uploadProducts(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'import_file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('import_file');

    $import = new ProductImport;

    Excel::import($import, $path);

    dd($import->product_ids); // it will return you an array

    return response()->json(['message' => 'uploaded successfully'], 200);
}
```